# How to copy text from an already open webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser, google-colaboratory

I'm using google colab to run stable diffusion and I want to make a txt file with all the prompts and settings. These are located in a div class element under the generated image in the web ui. I want a python code to copy the text (with the promots and settings) and save it in a txt file. How do I do this?

I've tried selenium but it opens a new window with the webpage each time which I dont want

Answer (score 0):

I don't think opened browser window can be attached to selenium.

You can run selenium first to open the browser window and visit google colab in that window, it can be manually operated same as normally opened browser window and accessible from selenium code.